# How can I add a grand total in a shopping cart in woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, sum, cart

This is the code of my shopping cart subtotals (item x qty):

```
<?php
      echo apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template' ,
WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $raq['quantity'] ));
?>
```

How can I add a grand total? (sum of all subtotals)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can post more (*relevant*) code to have more possibilities of answers, but if you create a method in 
`WC()->cart`
Maybe can calculate the total amount.
`WC()->cart->get_total_amout()`

I think because `WC()->cart` can handle with your basket.

Comment: I tried to use the same code with WC()->cart->get_total_amout() but i get the following message:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Cart::get_total_amout()